# Why do breakpoints jump around in .h files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug a .h file with getters / setters but while attached to the process I want to debug, when I place a breakpoint on certain methods, the IDE automatically jumps the breakpoint to a separate method in the file.  Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Some things I've tried:

- Rebuild and link the .exe I'm debugging
- Delete the .obj file, and remake the directory containing the file I want to debug
- Checked with task manager to ensure the correct .exe is running
- Checked timestamps of .pdb and .exe files to ensure they (roughly) match

This isn't a problem solution-wide; I only ever see this occasionally.  Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Try disabling optimizations. When your code gets optimized you lose the capability of properly navigating within it whilst debugging.

Comment: Another reason is that a function is never used, thus no code is generated for it in an optimized build.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on a line that does not generate binary code, the debugger automatically moves the breakpoint to the following line that does.

Comment: Not every asm code has a corresponding C++ code, e.g. the function stack frame setup.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a Point class and a Rectangle class.  Imagine that Point has a getter called GetX() and that Rectangle has a getter called GetLeft().  At the machine instruction level, these two methods might be identical, as they each return the first 32-bit value in the object.

Since the code is identical, the compiler and/or the linker could reduce the size of the binary by discarding one copy of the method and resolving all calls to the discarded one as calls to the retained one.  For example, the linker might drop Rectangle::GetLeft() from the executable and replace all the calls to Rect::GetLeft() with calls to Point::GetX().

When this happens, the debugger can no longer distinguish between GetX() and GetLeft().  Even if the call was to Rect::GetLeft(), the instruction pointer is in the range of code that belongs to Point::GetX().  You can tell the difference by looking up the stack to see which method was actually called, but the debugger isn't going to do that for you.

Typically, you build debug builds with optimization disabled to avoid debugging confusion of this sort.  That's not always possible.  For example, you might be debugging a crash dump from a customer who was running the optimized binary.  In that case, you simply have to be aware of the issue and be aware of the calling context to know what's really going on.